# How to prove combinatorial identities related to infinite series?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

This is an identity for the sum of combinatorial numbers. What techniques are used to prove it?

> \begin{align*}
> \dfrac{1}{4^n}\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2 i+k}\binom{2 i}{i} \binom{2 n-2 i}{n-i}=\dfrac{(k-2)\text{!!}}{(k-1)\text{!!}} \cdot\frac{(2n+k-1)\text{!!}}{(2n+k)\text{!!}}
> \end{align*}

I met this identity when expanding the series, but how to prove it?

\begin{align*}
S&=\dfrac{1}{k}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\prod _{j=1}^n (2 j+k-1)}{\prod _{j=1}^{n} (2j+k)}x^{2n+k}\\
&=\dfrac{(k-2)\text{!!}}{(k-1)\text{!!}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+k-1)\text{!!}}{(2n+k)\text{!!}}x^{2n+k}\\
&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2 n+k}}{4^n}\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2 i+k}\binom{2 i}{i} \binom{2 n-2 i}{n-i}\\
&=\left\{\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2m-1)\text{!!}}{\left[(2m)\text{!!}\right](2m+k)}
 x^{2m+k}\right\}\left[\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2m-1)\text{!!}}{(2m)\text{!!}}
 x^{2m}\right]\\
&=\left(\int_0^x \frac{t^{k-1}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \,\mathrm{d}t\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we proof the identity stated by OP for *even* $k$. We show the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2i+2k}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2n-2i}{n-i}=\frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!}\frac{(2n+2k-1)!!}{(2n+2k)!!}}\tag{1.1}
\end{align*}
In a first step we transform the right-hand side using binomial coefficients. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{(2k-2)!!}{(2k-1)!!}=\frac{(2k-2)!!(2k)!!}{(2k)!}=\frac{1}{2k}\,\frac{2^kk!2^kk!}{(2k)!}=\frac{4^k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\tag{2.1}
\end{align*}
where we use $(2k)!=(2k)!!(2k-1)!!=2^kk!(2k-1)!!$ and similarly we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n+2k-1)!!}{(2n+2k)!!}=\frac{1}{4^{n+k}}\binom{2n+2k}{n+k}\tag{2.2}
\end{align*}

Multiplying (2.1) with (2.2), putting them into (1.1) and canceling $\frac{1}{4^n}$ we have to show the validity of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2n-2i}{n-i}\frac{k}{i+k}=\binom{2n+2k}{n+k}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}}\tag{1.2}
\end{align*}

**Short Introduction:**

We will show (1.2) with the help of a bivariate generating function. The following approach is based on a highly instructive derivation from John Riordan in *[Combinatorial Identities](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1972-78-04/S0002-9904-1972-12968-9/S0002-9904-1972-12968-9.pdf)*. In fact we will see that this bivariate generating function is versatile, as it can be brought into different equivalent forms, each of them providing us with interesting binomial identities.

**Generating function: $b(x,y)$ - Part 1:**

We define with an eye toward the left-hand side of (1.2)
\begin{align*}
b(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y(1-4x)}}
\end{align*}
Binomial series expansion and a binomial identity gives us
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}=\sum_{q=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{q}(-y)^q=\sum_{q=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^q}\binom{2q}{q}y^q
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y(1-4x)}}}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^q}\binom{2q}{q}y^q\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}y^r(1-4x)^r\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{{q+r=n}\atop{q,r\geq 0}}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2r}{r}(1-4x)^ry^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n}{4^n}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2r}{r}\binom{2n-2r}{n-r}(1-4x)^r}\tag{3.1}
> \end{align*}

We see in (3.1) the inner sum is pretty close to the left-hand side of (1.2). What we need is some magic to come to the fraction $\frac{k}{i+k}$.

But as indicated above, the generating function $b(x,y)$ is flexible and so let's have a look outside the box. Factoring out $\frac{1}{1-y}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}$ and making a series expansion similar to the one above we get another nice representation:

**Generating function: $b(x,y)$ - Part 2:**

\begin{align*}
b(x,y)=\frac{1}{1-y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{4xy}{1-y}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}(-1)^qx^q\tag{3.2}
\end{align*}

But, that's not all, we can again transform $b(x,y)$ into something different to obtain

**Generating function $b(x,y)$ - Part 3:**

\begin{align*}
b(x,y)&=\frac{1}{1-(1-2x)y}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4x^2y^2}{1-(1-2x)y}}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{n}{2q} x^{2q}(1-2x)^{n-2q}\tag{3.3}
\end{align*}

**Identities derived from $b(x,y)$:**

Extracting from (3.1) to (3.3) the coefficient of $y^n$ from $b(x,y)$ and denoting it with $b_n(x)$ we obtain with
\begin{align*}
b(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(x)y^n
\end{align*}
the identities
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{b_n(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2n-2q}{n-q}(1-4x)^q}\tag{4.1}\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}(-x)^q}\tag{4.2}\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{n}{2q} x^{2q}(1-2x)^{n-2q}}\tag{4.3}
\end{align*}

**Identities derived from $b_n(x)$:**

We evaluate $b_n(x)$ at some specific values and obtain:

\begin{align*}
b_n\left(1/4\right)&=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^q\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{n}{2q}\frac{1}{2^{n+2q}}\\
\\
b_{2n}\left(1/2\right)&=\frac{1}{4^{2n}}\sum_{q=0}^{2n}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2n-2q}{2n-q}(-1)^q\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^q=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\\
\\
b_n(1)&=\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2n-2q}{n-q}(-3)^q
=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}(-1)^q\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{n}{2q}
\end{align*}
I think it's really nice to obtain such pretty cool identities from just one generating function $b(x,y)$. But now we will  focus on the original claim (1.x). We want to incorporate into (4.1) the fraction $\frac{k}{q+k}$ according to (1.2) and consider at first a helpful identity.

**Intermezzo: A helpful identity**

> The following identity is valid:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}\frac{k}{q+k}=\binom{k+n}{k}^{-1}}\tag{5 }
> \end{align*}

Denoting the left-hand sum of (5) with $f_n(k)$, it is straight forward to show
\begin{align*}
f_n(k)-f_{n-1}(k)=-\frac{k}{k+1}f_{n-1}(k+1)
\end{align*}
We calculate $f_n(0), f_n(1)$ from the left-hand side of (5) and consider the recursion
\begin{align*}
f_n(k)&=f_{n-1}(k)-\frac{k}{k+1}f_{n-1}(k+1)\\
f_0(k)&=1\\
f_1(k)&=\frac{1}{k+1}
\end{align*}
Iterating the recurrence we find
\begin{align*}
f_n(k)&=\frac{n!}{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)}=\binom{k+n}{k}^{-1}
\end{align*}
and the claim (5) follows.

Now we consider a variable transformation of $b_n$.

**Transformation: $b_n\left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)$**

We evaluate $b_n(x)$ at $\frac{1-x}{4}$ and focus on (4.1) and (4.2). We obtain
\begin{align*}
b_n\left(\frac{1-x}{4}\right)
&=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2n-2q}{n-q}x^q\tag{6.1}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^q(1-x)^q\tag{6.2}\\
\end{align*}

**Some little magic:**

We want to use (5) in (6.1). In order to do so we need some magic, which can be made rigorous by the *[umbral calculus](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-umbral-calculus)*.

We set
\begin{align*}
x^q\equiv x_q=\frac{k}{q+k}\tag{7.1}
\end{align*}
and obtain according to (5)
\begin{align*}
(1-x)^q=\sum_{j=0}^q\binom{q}{j}(-1)^j\frac{k}{k+j}=\binom{k+q}{k}^{-1}\tag{7.2}
\end{align*}
Using (7.2) the expression (6.2) becomes
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{b_n(k)=\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{k+q}{k}^{-1}\frac{1}{4^q}}\tag{7.3}
\end{align*}
We can easily verify
\begin{align*}
b_0(k)&=1\\
b_1(k)&=\frac{2k+1}{2(k+1)}\\
b_2(k)&=\frac{(2k+1)(2k+2)}{4(k+1)(k+2)}\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
\color{blue}{b_n(k)}&=\frac{(2k+1)(2k+3)\cdots(2k+2n-1)}{2^n(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)}=\cdots\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2k+2n}{k+n}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}}\tag{7.4}
\end{align*}
The *binomial inverse* of (7.3) is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{k+n}{k}^{-1}=\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}b_q(k)\tag{7.5}
\end{align*}
The relationship between the binomial identity (7.3) and its binomial inverse (7.5) is a consequence of the following relationship between two exponential generating functions $A(x)$ and $B(x)$:
\begin{align*}
A(x)=B(-x)e^x\quad&\longleftrightarrow\quad B(x)=A(-x)e^x\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}b_k\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\quad&\longleftrightarrow\quad
\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}b_k\quad&\longleftrightarrow\quad
 b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}a_k\\
\end{align*}

**Final steps:**

Assuming (7.4) is correct, we can put it into (7.5) to obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4^{k+n}}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{k+n}{k}^{-1}=\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}\binom{2k+2q}{k+q}\frac{1}{4^{k+q}}\tag{8.1}
\end{align*}
We can now verify (8.1) (and so also (7.4)) similarly as we did the verification for (5). Observing the symmetry between $n$ and $k$ in (8.1) we denote the right-hand sum of (8.1) by $f_n(k)$ and derive a recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
f_n(k)&=f_{n-1}(k)-f_{n-1}(k+1)\\
f_0(k)&=\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\\
f_n(0)&=\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\frac{1}{4^q}
=b_n\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align*}
Iterating the recurrence relation gives the left-hand side of (8.1). Taking the binomial inverse of (8.1), which is after cancelling $\frac{1}{4^k}$ and division by $\binom{2k}{k}$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^n(-1)^q\binom{n}{q}\binom{2q}{q}\binom{k+q}{k}^{-1}\frac{1}{4^q}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2k+2n}{k+n}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}\tag{8.2}
\end{align*}
we observe the left-hand side of (8.2) is $b_n(k)$ in the form of (7.3). Since we have the identities (6.1) *and* (6.2) at hand we can equivalently write $b_n(k)$ using (6.1) and (7.1) and derive finally the wanted identity (1.2)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{b_n(k)=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{2q}{q}\binom{2n-2q}{n-q}\frac{k}{q+k}=\binom{2k+2n}{k+n}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}}
\end{align*}

*Note:* A good starting point for examining this example in John Riordans classic *[Combinatorial Identities](https://archive.org/details/combinatorialide00john)* is Chapter three, *Inverse Relations II*, problem 9.

Comment: (+1). Your simplified version of the identity for even $k$ appears as 75.80 (FPS) in the following [list](http://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/egorychev-mathjax.html#gould3.95). It goes back to Gould's *Combinatorial Identities* number 3.95 on page 33.

Comment: Observe carefully that $$\sum_{q=0}^n {2n-2q\choose n-q} {2q\choose q} \frac{x}{x+2q} = \sum_{q=0}^n {2n-2q\choose n-q} {2q\choose q} \frac{x/2}{x/2+q}$$ so it is sufficient to evaluate the sum with $x/(x+q)$ where you need to turn your RHS into a rational function in $x$, consult above, which is $$2^{2n} {x+n\choose n}^{-1} {n+x-1/2\choose n}.$$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Great Marko! Many thanks for the hint and the link to your collection.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you're looking for (which is why I planned to leave it as a comment, but it got too long) but your sum is [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) in $i$, which means there's a computer algorithm that can compute a closed form for you. In fact, there are computer algorithms which will (almost always) give you a proof involving only basic algebra (though the resulting proof looks like magic, and would be almost impossible for a human to come up with!). Hopefully someone else comes along to give an analytic answer, but for now let's see how we can have a computer solve this problem for us:

First, let's talk about the sum. We can ask [sage](https://sagemath.org) to compute

$$
\frac{1}{4^n} \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{2j + k} \binom{2j}{j} \binom{2n-2j}{n-j}
$$

```
1/4^n * sum(1/(2*j + k) * binom(2*j, j) * binom(2*n - 2*j, n-j), j, 0, n)
```

(where I'm using $j$ as the variable because sage thinks $i$ is the complex unit) and it happily outputs

```
factorial(1/2*k)*factorial(1/2*k + n - 1/2)/(k*factorial(1/2*k + n)*factorial(1/2*k - 1/2))
```

or, more legibly,

$$
\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2} \, k\right)! \left(\frac{1}{2} \, k + n - \frac{1}{2}\right)!}{k \left(\frac{1}{2} \, k + n\right)! \left(\frac{1}{2} \, k - \frac{1}{2}\right)!}
$$

which we can quickly massage into your expression by using the well known identity
$\left ( \frac{k}{2} \right )! = \frac{k!!}{2^k}$.

Now, the algorithm that sage uses has been proven correct (for instance, in the book [A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html)), so barring implementation bugs, this sum is correct, and you can carry on with your research.

---

However, I mentioned at the start of this answer that there are computer algorithms which can give you an easy proof of the claim, but that it will look like magic. The relevant search term is "[WZ Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair)". There's also a nice discussion [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilf-ZeilbergerPair.html) and in chapter 7 of A=B.

For simplicity, let's look at the $k=2$ case. Then we're trying to prove

$$
\frac{1}{4^n} \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{2j+2} \binom{2j}{j} \binom{2n-2j}{n-j} 
= \frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}
$$

Equivalently, replacing the double factorials by single factorials and moving everything to the left hand side, we're trying to prove

$$
\sum_{j=0}^n F(n,j) 
= \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(n+1) \binom{2j}{j} \binom{2n-2j}{n-j}}{(j+1) (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}} 
= 1 \quad \quad (\star)
$$

now for the black magic: we can ask sage for the WZ certificate

```
F(n,j) = (n + 1)*binomial(2*j, j)*binomial(-2*j + 2*n, -j + n)/((j + 1)*(2*n + 1)*binomial(2*n, n))
F.WZ_certificate(n,j)
```

and sage tells us the certificate is

$$
R(n,j) = -\frac{{\left(2 \, j - 2 \, n - 1\right)} {\left(j + 1\right)} j}{{\left(j - n - 1\right)} {\left(2 \, n + 3\right)} {\left(n + 1\right)}}
$$

why care? Because even though we might not have been able to *come up* with $R$ by ourselves, once we have it it makes it almost trivial to prove $(\star)$! But since $\star$ is just a manipulation of our sum of interest, we'll be done. So let's see how to do it:

---

Let $G(n,j) = R(n,j) \cdot F(n,j)$. Then (tedious but) basic algebra shows that

$$G(n,j+1) - G(n,j) = F(n+1,j) - F(n,j)$$

if we sum this over all $j$, we see that

$$\sum_j G(n,j+1) - \sum_j G(n,j) = \sum_j F(n+1,j) - \sum_j F(n,j)$$

but, of course, the left hand side is $0$ since we're summing over all $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so the two $G$-sums are just reindexed versions of each other!

Then the right hand side is $0$ too, so $\sum_j F(n+1,j) = \sum_j F(n,j)$ and our sum is independent of $n$. But it's easy to check that $\sum_j F(0,j) = 1$, so we see that $\sum F(n,j) = 1$. As desired.

---

Unfortunately, sage is refusing to compute $R$ when we leave $k$ as a parameter, but if you really want a proof there's nothing stopping you from running the WZ algorithm by hand, keeping track of $k$ as you go. Alternatively, if you have access to mathematica or maple you can probably convince them to get the certificate for you.

---

I hope this helps ^_^